# custom google login button when used sdk in ios

Tags: ios, button, sdk, google-signin

I want to change the google login button shape and other details i have gone through the link [google developer](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/api/interface_g_i_d_sign_in_button#property-documentation) and try to change but did not get success as per my requirement  does any one know any other way to change button style , bg , text

Comment: what the output u need

Answer (score 1):

Take one Button in storyboard and design button as per your requirement take an action method in viewController

```
- (IBAction)YourGoogleButtonAction:(id)sender {
        [[GIDSignIn sharedInstance] signIn];
    }
```